How to Implement JWT Authentication with a Dynamic Database in Django? (User table is in each database its not central)
I'm working on a Django application where the user data is not stored in a central database. Instead, each client has their own separate database hosted on their own server.
Here's the setup:

JWT Authentication is used for the app.
The central Django server handles authentication requests but must dynamically connect to a client's specific database based on information provided in the JWT token.
The employee_id is stored in each client's database, not in the central Django database.
The connection string to the client's database is included in the JWT token payload.

My Implementation:
I've created a custom JWTAuthentication class where:

Token Validation: The JWT token is validated.
Database Connection: Based on the token payload, I dynamically connect to the client's database using the connection string provided in the token.
User Verification: I fetch the user from the client’s database using the employee_id in the token and check if the user is active.

Here's a simplified version of my JWTAuthentication class:
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework.request import Request
from .models import TokenUser
from .settings import api_settings
from .tokens import Token
from .exceptions import AuthenticationFailed, InvalidToken
import pymssql

class JWTAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request: Request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
        if header is None:
            return None

        raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None

        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token

    def get_user(self, validated_token: Token):
        employee_id = validated_token.get(api_settings.USER_ID_CLAIM)
        conn_string = validated_token.get('conn')
        role = validated_token.get('role')

        if not employee_id:
            raise InvalidToken("Token contained no recognizable user identification")

        if role == 0:
            # Local database user fetching logic
            try:
                user = self.user_model.objects.get(**{api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD: employee_id})
                if not user.is_active:
                    raise AuthenticationFailed("User is inactive", code="user_inactive")
                return user
            except self.user_model.DoesNotExist:
                raise AuthenticationFailed("User not found", code="user_not_found")
        else:
            # External database connection logic
            if not conn_string:
                raise InvalidToken("Token contained no connection string")

            def reconnect(conn_string):
                conn_details = conn_string.split(':')
                server, database, username, password = conn_details[1:5]
                return pymssql.connect(server=server, user=username, password=password, database=database)

            with reconnect(conn_string) as connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("""
                    SELECT [btEmpIsActive]
                    FROM [tblMstEmployee]
                    WHERE [inEmpId] = %s
                """, [employee_id])

                row = cursor.fetchone()
                if not row:
                    raise AuthenticationFailed("User not found in the external database", code="user_not_found")

                is_active = row[0]
                if not is_active:
                    raise AuthenticationFailed("User is inactive in the external database", code="user_inactive")

            return TokenUser(token=validated_token)

My Questions:

Is This Approach Secure?:

By connecting dynamically to client databases, am I exposing any significant security risks?
How can I ensure that the connection string is not tampered with in the token?


Handling User Verification:

Currently, I strictly verify the employee_id and the active status of the user. Is there a safe way to bypass or modify this verification if needed?
What best practices should I follow to securely manage user identification across multiple databases?


Alternative Approaches:

Are there alternative methods for handling authentication when the user table is not in a central database but spread across dynamic, client-specific databases?
Would using a microservices architecture with a dedicated authentication service be a better approach?



Additional Information:

Django Version: 3.x
Database: MSSQL (using pymssql for connections)
Authentication: JWT (with Django REST framework)

I'm open to suggestions or best practices that could make this setup more secure and efficient. Thank you in advance!
I want to build authentication system which will satisfy my situation where there is not one central database instead there are multiple clients databases in server

Does the connection string in your JWT token include the credentials to the database? Or, are you fetching the credentials from another source? JWT token payload is open to all and having database credentials might not be a good idea.

Yes, ohk but is there any other alternative?  I hope you have understood my problem i will explain it to you if not. Bcoz I wokring on app that will go into production and if i messed the logic then whole system will get messed up

Look so there is one central db where i am storing companies name and database connection string,the clients database are also on our vm but clients can access it by using ssms and there is attendance software who can also work with it. Now I am using JWt tokens on Android app where i have to build custom logic bcoz user table is not central its distributed and as u know u need to have user id or any other claim, i am confused in also that one. I guess if we fix the claim according my problem might get solved. Then i dont need sent db connection string in tokens payload

Hey, I got the answer i guess instead of passing connection string in tokens i can fetch from my central db where company id, code and connection string is stored so whenever user triggers api then using company id we can retrieve the connection string
